# What happened to the money?

Tags: plot-explanation, a-separation

I recently saw [Asghar Farhadi](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1410815)'s [A Separation](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1832382) (great movie). A major part of the movie revolves around the accident involving Razeih (the caretaker).

In the particular scene where Nader returns to his house to find his father lying unconscious and tied to the bed, Razieh is nowhere to be found. When she does return, Nader accuses her of neglecting his father and of having stolen money from his room. Now Razieh protests her innocence (which is later kinda' confirmed when her daughter tells Nader that she hadn't stolen the money) and it seems like that she is telling the truth.
Now my question is, if Razieh didn't take the money, the where did it go?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, IMDb [solves that mystery](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1832382/faq#.2.1.4): It was Simin who paid the movers.

> **Who took the money?**
>   *Simin*. There's a scene where Simin is arguing with workers who are moving the piano. They say that Simin must pay them more. Simin pays them the money, the same money that was put into the drawer. Later on, Nader thinks that Razieh has stolen the money.

IIRC, this happens at an early stage in the film. Nader was unaware of this.